# Cannot convert type 'string' to List<string> while deserialize JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to deserialize the JSON string to object.

Below is the JSON text,

```
{
    "id":1047,
    "name":"City",
    "attribute_list":"[\"RWC\",\"HMO\",\"SJ\",\"Ensenada\"]",
    "list_type":1
}
```

Class used are below,

```
public class TemplatesList
{
    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public List<Attributes> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Attributes
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("list_type")]
    public string ListType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("attribute_list")]
    public List<string> ComboBoxValue { get; set; }
}
```

Code used to deserialize is below,

```
records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TemplatesList>(json);
```

During deserialization, all the property are mapped correctly except `attribute_list`, I am getting the following error "`Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`", during deserialize the attribute_list field.

Please help me in fix this.

Thanks

Comment: In terms of JSON it's not a collection of strings, it's just a string

Comment: The commas being escaped in the `attribute_list` string means its just a string, not a collection

Comment: Ok. I need to add that values to a list. Is their any way to do it.

Comment: this is not a valid json, check here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Prany That's typo error while posting here, actual json will more attribute. Update in question.

Answer (score 2):

You need either change your JSON to the following removing escaping symbols:

```
{
  "id":1047,
  "name":"City",
  "attribute_list":["RWC","HMO","SJ","Ensenada"],
  "list_type":1
}
```

or create [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for your type which will process your attribute_list to the collection of strings

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
    public class Attributes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ListType { get; set; }
        private List<string> _ComboBoxValue { get;set;}
        public string ComboBoxValue
        {
            get
            {
                return "[\"" + string.Join("\",\"", _ComboBoxValue) + "\"]";
            }
            set
            {
                _ComboBoxValue = value.Split(new char[] { '[', ',', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json

```
var files = JObject.Parse(YourJSONHere);
var recList = files.SelectTokens("$").ToList();
foreach (JObject item in recList)
{
   foreach (JProperty prop in item.Children())
     {
            string key = prop.Name.ToString();
            string value = prop.Value.ToString();
            // or do whatever 
     }
}
```